# Who is the character that appears at the end of Endgame?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In Avengers: Endgame, Pepper Potts gets an iron suit at the climax fight scene. Is this a known character from the comics source? What is the name of this suit and character?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because 
**in the comics seems off-topic isnt it?

Comment: @Vishwa The character appears in the movie, but we're never told the characters name. If one officially exists, it would be nice to know it, the comics are just a reference point to name the movie character

Comment: Well, she is Pepper Potts.

Comment: In the first scenes the helmet of this character is called "a special gift for wedding day", so the source of it is clear. Name and character it have to earn ...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## Rescue

It's not named in the movie but in the comics it's called the "Rescue Suit".

> Spinning out of the Eisner-winning INVINCIBLE IRON MAN! When Tony Stark needed to save Pepper Potts' life, he gave her the Iron Man treatment -- with a repulsor chest implant and a suit of armor to call her own! Pepper went on to become Rescue, one of the heroes of the fan-favorite, critically acclaimed arc WORLD'S MOST WANTED! Now see one of Rescue's incredible solo adventures, as Pepper Potts lets loose with her bleeding-edge suit and her astonishing power!
>
> [**Marvel**](https://www.marvel.com/comics/issue/30249/rescue_2010_1)

[image]

Comment: Upvoted but I think at best this is loosely considered the same suit/character. Apart from stylistic changes(like the movie suit being blue), Pots definitely didnt have a repulsor chest implant or this side of the story carry on film.

Comment: Here's some more evidence for your answer: Hasbro released [a toy of the couple](https://www.polygon.com/2019/5/3/18528075/avengers-endgame-toys-hulk-stark-gauntlet-valkyrie-black-panther-spider-man-spoilers) using the name Rescue for Pepper Pott's suit.